# Cannot authorize my google app to access my Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have deployed an application on App Engine. Now I m trying to grant access to this app to be able to access my Cloud SQL instnace. The step is simple and straightforward as described here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access_control

However when I fill in the app id and push " save changes" I get the error:

"An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it."

Anybody has an idea about that issue?

UPDATE:

After spending some time on the issue I made the following observations:

I m located in the European Union. Therefore I created an Cloud SQL instance in the european Union zone. When I try to add an authorized application to my SQL instance I get the error that posted above: 
"An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it." 
Then I created a new SQL instance in United States. I was then able to authorize application for that instance. However my application was not able to access the US SQL instance since I guess my app is deployed somewhere in European Union.

Could someone from the google support team confirm my observations and explain me how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a known issue with Cloud SQL - currently the app and the Cloud SQL locations must match. Unfortunately you currently can't have a (free) EU app. So its catch 22 if you've chosen an EU Cloud SQL. You need to delete your current SQL instance and add a new one that is in the US.

That doesn't explain your second issue though - if the instance allows you to add the app, then the app must be in the US and you are facing a different issue. Also note that if you have a free app then it is by definition in the US - you can't currently choose app location on the free version.

I am not a Google support btw :D This info is from replies to me from Google people in the google group.

Comment: I encountered a (new?) error message: "App Engine regions must be the same as Cloud SQL instance region": http://cl.ly/image/2l161U0V1P1E

Answer (score 1):

Your GAE app and Cloud SQL instance must be in the same location:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#location

You can currently (Nov 27, 2012) create GAE apps in the EU only if you are a premier customer.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/location

Comment: Looks like you can now request access from the EU: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ